# visual studio split function issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I try to call split function on visual studio as below and i expect it return me 2 item in array after split, but vb return 5 results from my coding. It is consider vb issue or my coding issue?

Whole string is **"NAME":"ALICE"**

`Dim a As String = """NAME"":""ALICE"""
 Dim b() As String = a.Split(""":")`

Output I expected in array after split

(1) **"NAME**

(2) **"ALICE"**

[image]

Comment: How about regex?

Comment: Do you really expect the output of `"NAME`, `"ALICE"`? (Note the extra `"`s in your question)

Comment: @djv I noticed this as well...

Comment: vb cannot direct use colon in string, must use double colon in string. this why i put extra colon, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user1848681 you mean quote `"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using [this overload of String.Split(Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that takes an array of characters. String is convertible to an array of characters (and that's why you could compile) but it is not equal. Try putting `Option Strict On` at the top of your code. It won't compile as you have it anymore :)

When passing a single string, each character in the string is used to split. Including *each* `"` in your argument, `":`. It will split on `"` and `:`. You can get around it by passing a string array to Split using [this overload of String.Split(String[], SplitStringOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx). Pass a single element array like this

```
Dim b = a.Split({""":"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

[image]

Yes, that is exactly as you said,

- "NAME
- "ALICE"

Do you want to get rid of the quotes in the result? You can do this

```
Dim b = a.Split({":", """"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

[image]

Then it's this,

- NAME
- ALICE

Comment: Fixed it before you posted that :)

Comment: Hahahaaha nice!

Comment: vb give me Expression expected error message, this coding not accept by vb

Comment: I added SplitStringOptions, try again

Comment: this solution work for vs 2015, but not work for vs 2005. Anyway it help me a lot, Thank you for help.

Comment: @user1848681 it should work for 2005, well for .NET 2.0. Not sure if the compiler is different. I just tested it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i try already it prompt expression expected error message in 2005

Comment: I don't have VS 2005. Maybe the string array declaration shorthand is new since then? Try replacing `{""":"}` with `New String() {""":"}`

Comment: Yes it work for vs2005 after adding New String(), Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim a As String = """NAME"":""ALICE"""
    Dim b() As String = a.Split(":")
```

this is how it evaluates

[image]

Comment: It is cannot done in ": ? I code like this is because it possible contain ':' character between 'ALICE' like 'AL:ICE'

Comment: please show me the code(relevant lines) so that i can help you

Comment: This answer is not in vb.net

Comment: If a name has a colon how can you expect to split on colon?

Comment: Dim a As String = """NAME"":""ALICE"""
        Dim b() As String = a.Split(":")

Comment: i will replace : with /: before pass in to this function

Comment: how is the output if the string is Dim a As String = """NAME"":""A\:LICE"""